# ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras is not supported for tf version 1. See `model_builder.py`

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, checkpoint

hi i am facing a problem in Jupyter notebook i use python 3.7.13 and TensorFlow 1.15.5

```
# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_PATH, 'ckpt-7')).expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\Temp\ipykernel_6932\3048604568.py in 
> 1 # Load pipeline config and build a detection model
> 2 configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)
> ----> 3 detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)
> 4
> 5 # Restore checkpoint

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py in build(model_config, is_training, add_summaries)
1251     build_func = META_ARCH_BUILDER_MAP[meta_architecture]
1252     return build_func(getattr(model_config, meta_architecture), is_training,
-> 1253                       add_summaries)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py in _build_ssd_model(ssd_config, is_training, add_summaries)
400   """
401   num_classes = ssd_config.num_classes
--> 402   _check_feature_extractor_exists(ssd_config.feature_extractor.type)
403
404   # Feature extractor

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py in _check_feature_extractor_exists(feature_extractor_type)
268         '{} is not supported for tf version {}. See `model_builder.py` for '
269         'features extractors compatible with different versions of '
--> 270         'Tensorflow'.format(feature_extractor_type, tf_version_str))
271
272

ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras is not supported for tf version 1. See `model_builder.py` for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRWHY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91a6a.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see in [tensorflow model version 1.x](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/r1.13.0/research/object_detection/models) don't have ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras model. It is just supported from version 2.x. So you should install tensorflow object detection api version 2.0 and try again.

Comment: when i use tensorflow 2.x  i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' in this ligne from object_detection.builders import model_builder

Comment: TensorFlow.contrib does not exist in tensorflow 2.x. So I think you have to install [https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html](tensorflow object detection api version 2.0). ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras is supported by this version.